# Spring Boot: Refresh an entity within a service transaction which was updated by an external system call

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Given the following workflow in a Spring Boot application:

1. A `RestController` receives a request to update the `User` entity.
2. The controller delegates the updating to a `UserService`.
3. The `UserService` needs to call an external system which updates the `User` object on the same database instance. We're dealing with a legacy system here, so we need to stick to this fact.
4. The `UserService` needs to save the updated `User`.

I'm aware of the problem that #4 won't work as #3 has already updated the object.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final ExternalService externalService;

    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> createOrUpdateBewerberdaten(@RequestBody @Valid UserRequest userRequest) {
      UserResponse userResponse = userService.update(userRequest);
      return ResponseEntity.ok(userResponse);
}


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;
  private final ExternalService externalService;

  @Transactional
  public UserResponse update(UserRequest userRequest) {
    User user = userRepository.findById(userRequest.getId());
    user.setEmail(userRequest.getEmail());
    // this calls an external system via REST updating the user on the same database instance
    externalService.update(user);
    // this won't work as the user has been updated by externalService
    userRepository.save(user)
    return new UserResponse(user);
  }
}
```

Is there some pattern I could apply to get the latest version of the `User` object? My current approach is to call the `ExternalService` from the controller and put #4 in a dedicated public method, which is also annotated with `@Transactional`. However this feels like bloating the controller which I would like to keep as simple as possible.

Comment: I guess it will surely cost you either a db call post update or have to return something from legacy system so that current call stack may be sure that it's been updated.

Comment: Why do you have to call `userRepository.save(user)` at all if the external service is doing the update already? If all you want is to read the current state, just use `userRepository.refresh(user)`. Why does the `userRepository.save(user)` not work? Do you get an exception?